# MQTT java spring app accessing activemq on docker host fails to connect in brigde mode

Tags: spring, docker, activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

I have a Spring java app with *Paho* *MQTT* v3 connecting *ActiveMQ*.
The app is working well out of eclipse and started via *java -jar* and also inside my docker container as long as the network is in *host* mode. I tried the *host* mode because the *bridge* mode is not working. (my issue: connection reset)
I want to use the *bridge* mode because *host* mode I see as security issue. The app runs inside the container with limited rights. For testing purposes I have deactivated this so that I tested with uid 0. But this is not the problem.

The issue is, when I am running in *bridge* mode I get:

```
2020-11-30 19:58:54.192 ERROR 13 [                main]            n.w.s.s.s.MqttSender.startPublisher:53   : MqttException while starting mqtt message publisher. (resons code: 32103) : Unable to connect to server
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable to connect to server
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
        ... 2 common frames omitted
```

As I wrote I tried this:

- runing without docker => ok
- running in docker container in host mode => ok
- running in docker container in bridge mode => nok

I determined the mqqt host (docker host) by a script using "ip route" (alpine image)
I see in my log, that the default gateway ip is successfully determined and used.

I checked the firewalld setting and tested with netcat, if this could be the issue. But with nc I could not see an issue.

I checked with tcpdump and have seen that the connection is established. But then the mqtt client sends

- unsubscribe request
- disconnect request

I suppose that *ActiveMQ* says something like *unauthorized* because it is not connected of a private network (192.*.*.*). Instead the network in docker is something with 172.17.*.*
Otherwise the activemq listens on 0.0.0.0:1883.
Even via ssh tunnel I could connect.

I added the paho reson code to log. I got 32103.

Has anybody an idea what could happen here?

This is the traffic grabbed by tcpdump

```
1   0.000000    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 74  43482 ? 1883 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=715574721 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   0.000112    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  TCP 74  1883 ? 43482 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=715574722 TSecr=715574721 WS=128
3   0.000148    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 66  43482 ? 1883 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=715574722 TSecr=715574722
4   0.328363    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  MQTT    100 Connect Command
5   0.328505    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  TCP 66  1883 ? 43482 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=35 Win=29056 Len=0 TSval=715575050 TSecr=715575050
6   0.330538    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  MQTT    70  Connect Ack
7   0.330612    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 66  43482 ? 1883 [ACK] Seq=35 Ack=5 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=715575052 TSecr=715575052
8   0.341795    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  MQTT    83  Subscribe Request (id=1) [sensordata]
9   0.343407    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  MQTT    71  Subscribe Ack (id=1)
10  0.383106    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 66  43482 ? 1883 [ACK] Seq=52 Ack=10 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=715575105 TSecr=715575065
11  3.289301    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  MQTT    82  Unsubscribe Request (id=2)
12  3.290162    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  MQTT    70  Unsubscribe Ack (id=2)
13  3.290252    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 66  43482 ? 1883 [ACK] Seq=68 Ack=14 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=715578012 TSecr=715578012
14  3.293894    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  MQTT    68  Disconnect Req
15  3.295862    172.17.0.1  172.17.0.2  TCP 66  1883 ? 43482 [FIN, ACK] Seq=14 Ack=70 Win=29056 Len=0 TSval=715578017 TSecr=715578015
16  3.335121    172.17.0.2  172.17.0.1  TCP 66  43482 ? 1883 [ACK] Seq=70 Ack=15 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=715578057 TSecr=715578017
```

In ActiveMQ I have just enabled the MQTT transort connector. Security I don't enabled.
Do I have to configure something more in *ActiveMQ*?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65080712/edit) the question to include the information about how you have configured the container ports exposed.

Comment: My ActiveMQ is on docker host. The service inside does not offer any service to outside. Why I should expose a port?